Tree node indexing
I'd appreciate any solutions, ideas, or pointers to relevant literature.
I'm attempting to design a system with nodes (representing the state of some tasks) organised in a tree structure. I'd like to attach some "local index" metadata to each node such that given the "local index" of any two nodes, I can immediately tell if one node is the ancestor of another.
In this tree, nodes are only ever added, (conceptually) never updated/deleted. Nodes can be added as children to any (alive) node in the tree, and the number of children of each node is unbounded. I wanted to store this information within each node, because nodes in this tree should be oblivious to their siblings (who may have completed their purpose and been garbage collected).
I was hoping to achieve this in a way where the relevant metadata is relatively small. Otherwise, I could simply assign some counter as an identifier to each node, and for each node, store a list of the identifiers of the nodes on the path from the node through its ancestors to the root. This way, I would be able to compare whether two nodes are ancestors of each other by checking if the path of one node is the prefix of the other. However, this seems expensive (in both space and time), especially as the depth of the tree could be unbounded.
Another idea I had was to exploit the structure of trees as interval graphs, and assign two integers to each vertex of the tree such that the two integers correspond to the maximum and minimum of the intervals of its children. This would have worked (I think), if we knew the number of children of each node beforehand. In this scheme, assuming I had a graph
            A
            |
    -----------------
   |                 |
   B                 C
   |
  ------
 |      |
 D      E

We could assign a counter as identifier to each leaf in the tree.
            A
            |
    -----------------
   |                 |
   B                 C
   |                (3)
  ------
 |      |
 D      E
(1)    (2)

and simply declare such an "index" to be the interval of its children like so:
             A
           (1-3)
             |
      -----------------
     |                 |
     B                 C
   (1-2)             (3-3)
     |               
   ------
  |      |
  D      E
(1-1)  (2-2)

This way, I could tell whether one node is the ancestor of another by checking if the interval span of one node lies within that of another. However, this does not work if we want to add a node to an existing leaf, as we would have to expand not only the range of all the node's ancestors (somewhat slow), but also increment every other node after the inserted node.

Look for resources on 'dynamic least common ancestor' data structures. Then 'is node A an ancestor of B' becomes LCA(A, B) == A.

Delighted to see Orson Peters hanging around here! Thanks for your pointer, let me look it up.

With gratitude to Peters, https://dl.acm.org/doi/pdf/10.5555/314500.314564 seems to be the authoritative paper on the problem based on a cursory review. I see that it seems to address many of the problems I faced when attempting to attack the problem, such as how to efficiently reindex parents on insertions. Let me digest this paper and see if it is implementable "oblivious to siblings".

The static algorithm mentioned by the paper using the idea of centroid paths is indeed very elegant in solving the problem; in comparison, the 'dynamic' variant introduced by the paper to overcome its shortcomings is probably one of the most mind-bendingly dizzying and complicated algorithms involving parts of parts of parts of machinery, 'partially' maintaining multiple invariants over a dual pair of codes by scheduling n tree-interleaved processes "cup-filling with dated priorities" guarded by mutex-like machinery to implement multiple algorithmic procedures...

...one of which is a garbage collector-like machinery over an induced tree of subtrees over the binarization of the original tree, organised in a multi-layer scheme to launder logarithmic into constant time...
Who thought that determining ancestorhood was so difficult! It would probably take a much better man than I to implement this algorithm efficiently or with any degree of confidence. Such a complicated procedure makes me wonder if the constant of the algorithm were large; even dynamic succint trees (which support LCA in a simple way!) are vastly simpler than this dynamic algorithm.

...well... I suppose I can always implement the static algorithm mentioned, with fistfuls of caches on top.

P.S. What I linked to, which I thought was the paper, is apparently the abstract; see the last paragraph.

Long story short, I don't believe the paper convinces that God allowed this algorithm to exist.
